# Empty Multiple UILabel values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uilabel

I have multiple uilabels values.
I need to empty the UILabels self.lbl_title when I click on button NEXT.

How can I do this?

`self.lbl_title.hidden=true` not working in this case.

```
-(void)fetchdata
{

    int y=10;
    if(arrayquestion.count!=0){
    for (int i=0;i<arrayquestion.count;i++)
    {
        CGSize textsize = [[[arrayquestion objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"question_title"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(850, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

        self.lbl_title=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.lbl_title.frame= CGRectMake(60,y-3,900,textsize.height+5);
        self.lbl_title.text=[[arrayquestion objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"question_title"];
        self.lbl_title.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        self.lbl_title.numberOfLines=0;
        self.lbl_title.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
         y=y+textsize.height+30;

        [self.scrll_vw addSubview:self.lbl_title];

    }

    }
   else{
       NSLog(@"%s","Yes");
       self.lbl_title.hidden = YES;

    }  
}

-(IBAction)Next:(id)sender
{
    [arrayquestion removeAllObjects];
      [self fetchdata];
}
```

Comment: are you want set label text blank ? self.lbl_title.text = @"";

Comment: I check your code. I found that you didn't initialise self.lbl_title. Without initialise you didn't hide a label. I think so something like this happen

Comment: Every time fetchdata is called you are creating 10 new labels, assigning each in turn to `self.lbl_title`. At the end of the loop you only have a reference to the 10th label. Add them all to an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just clear the label text, you can use

```
self.lbl_title.text = @"";
```

Comment: i have tried this also. it is just empty the last value. @olga-nesterenko

Comment: it can be better for you to store in your property not the label itself, but the array of labels, which you add in a loop. so, when you need to clear them all, you just iterate your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also with reload `scrollview` because you need to clear old refrence of `UILable`

Remove old `UILable` then call your method:`[self fetchdata]`
        it will work defiantly

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
 for (UILabel *view in self.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if (![UILabel isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [UILabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [arrayquestion removeAllObjects];
      [self fetchdata];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the subviews inside your scrollView and find the label and empty it or hide it. Something like:

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

     //if you have only one label use the following:
     if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
         [obj setHidden:YES]
     }
    }];
```

Or if you have multiple UILabels, you can assign the specific label a tag value like 100 and use:

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

         //if you have only one label use the following:
         if (obj.tag == 100){
             [obj setHidden:YES]
         }
   }];
```